# Please check my math homework!

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

Could someone please check my math homework?

> 2 + 2 = 5
> 4 × 6 = 12
> 6<sup>2</sup> = 24
> 85 - 42 = 20
> √961 = 13
> 4<sup>3</sup> = 49
> 93 modulo 7 = 16
> 143 ÷ 13 = 4

I think I did it well...

*Note: This **is** a puzzle.*

Comment: Hi @Ausername, welcome to Puzzling SE! Would it be possible to convert the image into text for accessibility purposes? Thanks, and nice first puzzle!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most obvious first step to do is to

> find the actual answers to the expressions. In order from top to bottom, they are: 4, 24, 36, 43, 31, 64, 2, 11.

Next, we

> take the absolute difference between the correct and written answers. This gives us: 1, 12, 12, 23, 18, 15, 14, 7.

Finally,

> applying the A1Z26 transformation to these differences yields the phrase **ALL WRONG**. I don't know, but something tells me that you may need to double check your work here...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was your thought process that led to this? I looked at this puzzle and was like - I have no idea of where to even start...

Comment: @Vilx- [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(Gur svefg guvat V abgvprq jnf gung nyy gur nafjref jrer vapbeerpg, fb gur pbeerpg nafjref zhfg or vzcbegnag fbzrubj. Nsgre svaqvat gubfr, V gbbx gur qvssrerapr orgjrra gur pbeerpg naq tvira nafjref, juvpu vf n pbzzba znavchyngvba jurarire lbh unir cnvef bs ahzoref. Gung cebqhprq vagrtref gung jrer ab terngre guna 26, juvpu jnf n fvta gung jr fubhyq nccyl n N1M26 fhofgvghgvba. Fher rabhtu, nccylvat gung fhofgvghgvba tnir gur svany nafjre!) (Copy and paste this text into the link provided to decode it as it contains spoilers)

Comment: Also, I've seen other puzzles with this mechanism before, so it was easier to spot. Sometimes solving puzzles just comes down to experience!